# Name conflict behavior

Tags: sharepoint-online, file, flow, move, rename

In SharePoint online when my flow moves the file (PDF, ZIP...) named "U000" in a folder where is a file with the same name it renames the file in "U000**1**".

How can I customize this to be renamed like "U000**_Rev.1**" or "U000**_copy(1)**" instead of "U000**1**"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is default SharePoint behavior. What you can do is before moving check if the file with same name exists and then move the file with your desired name by renaming the file and then moving.

Comment: Thanks for your response but maybe I can change or add a code in "definition.json" file from exported ZIP flow (or somewhere else).